# indian visa rejection: mistaken identity

Tags: india, bangladeshi-citizens, visa-rejections

I am a Bangladeshi citizen. I applied for the indian visa back to back 3 times and every time they rejected my visa. somehow I get to know that my name Mohammad Hossain which is a similar kind of name  matched with some terrorist... so funny it is to me... so for that reason they consider me or my passport into blacklist... 
Now what can I do for that... I really need the visa as I want to go there for my wedding shopping in july.